# How to get winSize in Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I used below code in Cocos2d 1.0 and Cocos2d 2.0, but it seems not found in Cocos2d 3.0

```
CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
```

How to get screen size in Cocos2d 3.0 ?

Answer (score 31):

You can use viewSize.

```
    CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;
```

Comment: This returns `{512.00, 384.00}` on an iPad Air device and simulator.  Any idea why?  (Cocos2D version 3.4.3-develop).

Comment: @trojanfoe, I just logged size from cocos2d 3.4.3 and got (768.0,1024.0). I took Cocos2d from Sprite builder and working good.

Comment: Well it's weird as using `viewSizeInPixels` (is it?) returns the expected 2048 x 1536, which I am now using to calculate the global scale value.

Comment: I believe this is because viewSize returns the OpenGL size, while size in pixels is the actual device screen size. (just a theory though)

Comment: Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize() does return the actual device size though, but this is for cocos2dx