# Handle iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus size in cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, size

I am developing new game with support of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. I know the size's

```
iPhone 6 : 750 X 1334 pixels (4.7inches)
iPhone 6 Plus : 1242 X 2208 pixels (5.5inches)
```

How can i handle this sizes in cocos2d.
How can identify the iPhone (3.5inches, 4inches, 4.7inches, 5.5inches).
Can any one help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845981/how-to-get-winsize-in-cocos2d-3-0

Comment: check this out ,it might help :http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/iphone-6-ios-resolutions-and-assets/15062